# Do merging BHs have two or just one singularity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

There are a lot of questions about BH mergers on this site, and based on those, there are two main possibilities:

1.

Initially, the merged BHs, now a joint single BH, have two singularities, that move towards each other. That is, for a certain amount of time, there exist two different singularities inside a single (joint) EH.
And based on the statements, it is now unclear whether a merging BH binary has two or just one singularity inside the joint EH. 
This is after the EHs have joined, that is, when we have a single EH, that incorporates now both BHs, both previously existed singularities.

2.

The other argument is, that the joint EH cannot have two singularities, as the singularity is not a place in space, but it is a future point in time. As a future point in time cannot be binary, it has to be a single point in the future. All matter/light has to move towards that single point in the future called singlularity.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1M-AbWIlVQ&feature=youtu.be

Question:

1. Do merging BHs have two or just one singularity?

Comment: Are you asking about an ideal head-on collision between two non-spinning black holes? Or do you want to know what happens in a more realistic BH merger, where both BHs are likely to have substantial spin (and therefore ring singularities) as well as substantial orbital angular momentum?

Comment: @PM2Ring No, not a collision, just a merger.

Comment: When 2 Schwarzschild black holes approach each other, they do so at relativistic speed. So I think it's appropriate to call such a merger a collision. If the approach isn't perfectly head-on, they will develop appreciable angular momentum as they fall into an orbit about their common centre of mass, and radiate a lot of energy in gravitational waves.

Comment: @safesphere "Real black holes are empty with no matter or singularity inside" can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score -1):

The answer to the question are there initially two singularities in a merged black hole or only one depends on which singularity we talk about.

If Schwarzschild black holes are considered then the merged black hole has one singularity which is a point in time and which is not part of the manifold. It is well known that the Schwarzschild singularity is in conflict with General Relativity though. The singularity problem is hoped to be resolved by a future theory of quantum gravity where the mass is assumed to be contained in a tiny volume at e.g. Planck density. We then talk about astrophysical black holes with their "singularity" being a part of the manifold which means that after the merger of the black holes their "singularities" will merge.

Comment: General Relativity leads to infinite curvature for a gravitational singularity which is assumed non-physical..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity "The quantities used to measure gravitational field strength are the scalar invariant curvatures of spacetime, which includes a measure of the density of matter. Since such quantities become infinite at the singularity, the laws of normal spacetime break down". Note that said laws are the laws of General Relativity and that "break down" means "are inconsistent".

Comment: You don't get the point. Try to think in terms of "diverging", a divergent sequence doesn't have a limit. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0449.pdf  "...Both these models
contained a spacetime singularity where the curvatures as well as the matter and energy densities were
diverging getting arbitrarily high, and the physical description would then break down."